# Pushing to C2DM with node.js

Tags: node.js, android-c2dm

I'm trying to push out a notification to the C2DM server with node.js, but I'm getting nothing. Trying port 80 yields a 404, while trying port 143 yields nothing.

I've successfully run this curl command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=[auth cookie]" "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=[reg id] -d "data.payload=payload" -d collapse_key=0
```

but, while appearing to be similar, I can't get the node.js counterpart to work. Any ideas?

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var post_domain = 'https://android.apis.google.com';
var post_port = 143;
var post_path = '/c2dm/send';

var post_data = querystring.stringify({
  'registration_id' : '[reg id]',
  'collapse_key': '0' ,
  'data.payload' : 'Hello!'
});

var post_options = {
  host: post_domain,
  port: post_port,
  path: post_path,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
  'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth': '[auth cookie]'
  }
};

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
  });
});

// write parameters to post body
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` show?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Instagram's library for pushing messages to C2DM: https://github.com/Instagram/node2dm